# Need help isolating a laptop camera related issue (camera does not start on Chrome, but would otherwise work fine, only happens to 1 tester)

Tags: manual-testing, chrome

We are testing the upload camera video functionality on a website, however a tester from my team for some reason has a Chrome issue with her camera not turning on whenever she clicks the button on the site to start the camera, the light turns on for a second and immediately turns off.  Other than that her camera is functional, and this test does not fail for other testers, only her, everybody else is able to upload the camera video.  I want to really make sure we know if it's a hardware issue or if there is a bug on the website.  Can anyone recommend any tool that would help me isolate the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons why her camera does not work. Starting from the hardware problem, old drivers etc, finishing with antivirus software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal approach:

- Find an identical laptop with the same type of camera and try this again, see it happens.

What I would look for:

- From this laptop's specification sheet, what type of camera is it?
- What is this camera's firmware version? Can you update it to the latest version?
- Chrome version, this tester may have a different version of Chrome installed than everyone else. Can you update it to the latest version?

You can also try a "webcam" testing website to see if this webcam will work.

The unlikely worst scenario, is her camera controlled by other software on her laptop that she is unware of?

Comment: Thanks a lot! we managed to isolate it to a motherboard update, once we updated it the webcam worked